# Duplicates in Kafka synchronization in Seatunnel

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-seatunnel

I am currently working on synchronizing messages from a Kafka source to a Kafka sink, where both the source and sink topics reside on different clusters. The sink Kafka is set up as a disaster recovery solution. My intended scenario is that even after restarting the sink Kafka, it should be able to read messages from the last offset without producing duplicates.

However, upon conducting multiple tests of the aforementioned scenario, I've noticed that occasionally, after a restart, some records are duplicates in the sink Kafka, and the synchronization is not occurring as expected. I have included my configuration details below.

What can I try to resolve this?

Kafka Command used to create the topics:

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic source --bootstrap-server
> instance-3:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic sink --bootstrap-server
> instance-4:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1

Seatunnel Execution Command

> bin/seatunnel.sh --config ./config/kafka-cdc.conf -e local

**kafka-cdc.conf**

```
# Defining the runtime environment
env {
  # You can set flink configuration here
  job.mode = "STREAMING"
}
source {
  Kafka {
    result_table_name="kafka-cdc"
    topic = "source"
    bootstrap.servers = "instance-3:9092"
    kafka.config = {
      auto.offset.reset = "earliest"
      enable.auto.commit = "true"
    }
}
}
sink {
  Console {
  source_table_name="kafka-cdc"
  }
  kafka {
      source_table_name="kafka-cdc"
      topic = "sink"
      bootstrap.servers = "instance-4:9092"
      kafka.config = {
        acks = "all"
        request.timeout.ms = 60000
        buffer.memory = 33554432
    }
      format = text
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you reposted this question? Again, what's wrong with MirrorMaker, which was built for this purpose for Kafka?